# CSS Dropdown falling after leaving a space (Snap Attached) how to eliminate the space?

Tags: html, css

I created a dropdown menu and I am trying to get rid of the little space that I am getting at the beginning of the dropdown, between the parent component and its children, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want the drop down to begin from where the tab starts, something like this:

```
--------
| Parent
-----------
| Child
------------
```

Please, find a code snippet attached below:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 138.7px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: green;
}

li:hover ul a {
  background: grey;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
}

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Somthing</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">something</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">somethoing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `li ul {padding-left: 0;}`

Comment: i think, i was first) his answer was the same as i write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the padding to 0 on your hidden class. `.hidden{padding: 0;}` and also remove the `li ul li a{width:auto; min-width:100px;}` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5caj0he/) I changed your media query so it can be viewed in here.

```css
    ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        }
    li {
        display:inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1px;

    }
    li a {
        display:block;
        min-width:138.7px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        background: #2f3036;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;

    }
    li:hover a {
        background:green ;
    }
    li:hover ul a {
        background: grey;
        color: #2f3036;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
         text-align:center;

    }
    li:hover ul a:hover {
        background: green;
        color: #fff;
    }
    li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    li ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
 
    .hidden{
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
        display:block;
        width: auto;
    }
        #menu{
             text-align:center;
        }
    @media screen and (max-width : 460px){
        ul {
            position: static;
            display: none;
        }

        li {
            margin-bottom: 1px;
        }

        ul li, li a {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .show-menu {
            display:block;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">something</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: heyy thanks! if i wanted to keep the width of the child title in the drop down same as the parent, any idea how should i go about for the mentioned purpose? i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
li{position: relative;}
ul li ul{padding: 0; width: 100%;}
```